# Extract data from csv in RASA

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-x

I am making a chatbot in RASA which helps High school graduates find university according to their desired location. I have all my data stored in a CSV file. So is there any way we can extract some specific data from that CSV.
Example: If a user asks to show universities available in a certain location, how to extract the specific data from CSV which is the name of the university according to the location given by the user.

Comment: have you looked at `pandas` for reading csv?

Comment: @Kenan yes i have tried that but I'm having issue in extracting a specific data as requested by the user. so if a user asks a location of a university in a specific area how should i be doing that?

Comment: Have you looked at custom actions in Rasa? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvHg7N8ux2I&t=1s
You can write a custom action to extract info from a database, which can be in a csv format read in using pandas.

Comment: can you show some rows of the csv file.

Comment: College                                           location  
The British College, Kathmandu  Trade Tower    
Kathmandu Engineering College  Ganeshman Singh Rd  
So these are some of my data @Kenan

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you will need to train the model with location entity. Create a story that will link an intent with location entity to a custom action.

Sample story could like something like this:

> ### story 1
>
> ```
> * ask_university{"location":New York}
>  - action_get_universities
> ```

In the custom action `action_get_universities`, you will then need to handle the CSV query based on the location entity that the model detected. Pandas should work just fine.

Have fun exploring !